# Как подключить Local Storage к скрипту?

Tags: jquery, localstorage

Есть переключатель:

```
$(".main-nav-chat .options").click(function() {
  $(".wrapperchat").toggleClass("wrapperchat-bottom");
});
```

Как к нему привязать Local Storage, чтобы запоминался класс `wrapperchat-bottom`?

Можно его переделать, только чтобы смысл не поменялся.

Comment: Да.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapperchat">
   <div class="main-nav-chat">
      <div class="options">кнопка</div> 
   </div>
</div>

var active = localStorage['active'] == 'true';
$(".wrapperchat").toggleClass("wrapperchat-bottom", active);
$(".main-nav-chat .options").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    active = !active;
    localStorage['active'] = active;
$(".wrapperchat").toggleClass("wrapperchat-bottom");
});
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); не нужен, у дива нет действия по умолчанию.